# Kivy: Make class A's method affect class B's object's property?

Tags: python-2.7, methods, kivy, object-reference

I have been working with Kivy for the past 3 weeks to build a GUI for a radio simulator with two radios, each with a 16-button keypad, multi-position knob, and data display.

How do I refer to objects in my .kv file to act on them with methods declared by a different object in the .py file? I can use *self* to make an object do things to itself, but I cannot figure out how to make one object's method influence another object.

In the .kv below, I can use *on_press()* to make a button change the text property of another object. However, I am too indented to add a conditional action, such as: if knob8.index == 0, then radio_output.text = radio_output.text + '0'. Apparently I must use my own methods, but I don't understand how to reference or affect other objects through them.

A ScreenManager object is my root and contains 3 Screen objects. ScreenTwo is where I am working now. I want to be able to use the *change_image()* method of *Knob_8_Pos* to change the value of any property of the *Button* in the .kv file below. Being able to do so would open the door to much more functionality, because the knob's position determines what the multiple buttons can do and when.

I have tried to use *ids[]* in the method but failed. I had hoped to use something like *parent* to refer to an object one level higher in the hierarchy from the object calling the function, but that was not an option.

```
<ScreenTwo>:
    FloatLayout:
        id: screentwo_layout

    DisplayLabel:
        id: radio_output
        text: 'Buttons and stuff change this field'

    Button:
        id: button_0
        text: "but_0"
        size_hint: 0.06,0.1
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.2, 'center_y':0.47}
        on_press: 
            radio_output.text = radio_output.text + '0'
            print(radio_output.text)
        background_normal: 'Images/normal.png'
        background_down: 'Images/down.png'
        border: 20,20,20,20

    Knob_8_Pos:
        id: knob8
        size_hint: 0.19,0.35
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.725, 'center_y':0.38}
        on_press:
            self.change_image(self)
```

The method *change_image()* is in my main.py file, some of which follows. I have been playing with the last line of the method, but non-existent attributes or undefined global variables and other things keep crashing the program. I tried making a Radio class from Widget to hold a FloatLayout with Buttons, Knob, and Display, since I thought that would facilitate referencing object, but that has been an utter failure so far.

```
class Knob_8_Pos(Button):
    knob_index = BoundedNumericProperty(0, min=0, max=7, errorvalue=0)
    knob_pict = ListProperty(['knob_0.png','knob_1.png','knob_2.png',...])

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Knob_8_Pos, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.background_normal = 'Images/knob_0.png'

    def change_image(self, touch):
        self.knob_index += 1
        self.background_normal = self.knob_pict[self.knob_index]
        self.background_down = 'Images/knob_down.png'
        if self.knob_index == 0:
            print('Knob_index is zero.')
            self.ids[button_0].text = 'Changed'
```

Answer (score 1):

why not send button0 to the change_image class?

```
Knob_8_Pos:
    id: knob8
    size_hint: 0.19,0.35
    pos_hint: {'center_x':0.725, 'center_y':0.38}
    on_press:
        self.change_image(button_0)
```

And you change its text like this

```
def change_image(self, button0): # <----
    self.knob_index += 1
    self.background_normal = self.knob_pict[self.knob_index]
    self.background_down = 'Images/knob_down.png'
    if self.knob_index == 0:
        print('Knob_index is zero.')
        button0.text = 'Changed' #<----
```